# How do I round and make comparisons with PyMC3 prior parameters in a model?

Tags: python, theano, curve-fitting, bayesian, pymc3

I apologize in advance if it seems more complex than needed. Tried to make it more minimal than this, but then some of the questions were more difficult to formulate. This way it is as close as possible to my situation. What I have is some data that I want to fit with a function similar to what is described below. But when implementing the pyMC3 fit, as in the second code section, I run into the errors relating to the two questions.

```
# some constants and fixed things
rin = 1.
rout = 1000.
tmin = 10.
x = np.arange(0.1, 10, 0.2)

# parameters to be fitted
a = 4.0
b = 0.5
c = 10

# define r_struct, depends on b, but is one value
r_struct = 0.1**(1./b)

# nrad below, the number of radial points,  
# depends on r_struct and the constant rout
# QUESTION 1 here
nrad = round(r_struct, -1) + round((rout - r_struct)/10., -1) * 2

# define the radial bins, logarithmically spaced
rbins = np.logspace(np.log10(rin), np.log10(rout), num=nrad+1, endpoint=True)
rad = 10**(( np.log10(rbins[1:]) + np.log10(rbins[:-1]))/2.)
t = rad**(-b)

# QUESTION 2 here
# t cannot go below tmin, so I do this
t[t < tmin] = tmin

# then I want to know where the limit of r_struct is here
iout = rad > r_struct
iin = rad <= r_struct

# depending on if rad is past r_struct or not
# I do two different things.
c1  = c_struct * (rad[iin]/50.)**(-1.*a)
taper = np.exp( -(rad[iout]/rad[iout][0])**(2.-a) )
c2 = c_taper * taper/taper[0]
tau = np.append(c1, c2) 

y_true = J0( x[:, np.newaxis] * rad) * (t * (1.0 - np.exp(-1.*tau) ) )
y_true = y_true.sum(axis=1)

y_obs = y_true + np.random.normal(size=len(x))*50
y_error = np.ones_like(y_true)*0.1*y_true.max()

plt.errorbar(x,y_obs, yerr= y_error, color='r', marker='.', ls='None', label='Observed')
plt.plot(x,y_true, 'b', marker='None', ls='-', lw=1, label='True')
plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y'); plt.legend()
```

[image]

OK so now I want to fit this in PyMC3. I started with the following.

```
with pm.Model() as basic_model:
    # parameters
    a = pm.Uniform("a", 0, 10)
    b = pm.Uniform("b", 0, 10)
    c = pm.Uniform("c", 0,100)

    r_struct = 0.1**(1./b)
    nrad = round(r_struct, -1) + round((rout - r_struct)/10., -1) * 2

    rbins = np.logspace(np.log10(rin), np.log10(rout), num=nrad+1, endpoint=True)
    rad = 10**(( np.log10(rbins[1:]) + np.log10(rbins[:-1]))/2.)
    t = rad**(-b)

    t[t < tmin] = tmin
    iout = rad > r_struct
    iin = rad <= r_struct

    c1  = c_struct * (rad[iin]/50.)**(-1.*a)
    taper = np.exp( -(rad[iout]/rad[iout][0])**(2.-a) )
    c2 = c_taper * taper/taper[0]

    tau = np.append(c1, c2) 
    y_true = J0( x[:, np.newaxis] * rad) * (t * (1.0 - np.exp(-1.*tau) ) )
    y_true = y_true.sum(axis=1)

    func=pm.Deterministic('gauss',y_true)

    y = pm.Normal('y', mu=func, tau=1.0/y_error**2, observed=y_obs)

    trace = pm.sample(5000)
```

However this fails already at the first "round()" call. See questions below.

**QUESTION 1.** *"nrad" needs to be an integer, it depends on the pymc3 prior "b" (through r_struct), how do I round it to and integer when running PyMC3?*
For reference, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-fcf897a21b89> in <module>()
     15     r_struct = 0.1**(1./b)
     16
---> 17     nrad = round(r_struct, -1) + round((rout - r_struct)/10., -1) * 2
     18     rbins = np.logspace(np.log10(rin), np.log10(rout), num=nrad+1, endpoint=True)

TypeError: type TensorVariable doesn't define __round__ method
```

**QUESTION 2:** *How do I make comparisons with an array created with a PyMC3 prior?* The code fails at the comparison.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-7f77e70d147a> in <module>()
     26     t = rad**(-b)
     27
---> 28     t[t < tmin] = tmin
     29     iout = rad > r_struct
     30     iin = rad <= r_struct
```

Any suggestions on how to clarify the question, including the title are all welcome!

Comment: Does it run with `step=pm.Metropolis()`?  I suspect the discontinuous nature of the `round` operation is problematic for differentiating the compute graph.  If you reparameterize so that `b` is discrete from the start, then if you don't specify the step PyMC will automatically use Metropolis just on that parameter, and NUTS on the others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @merv. However, `b` needs to be continuous, it's just that I use it to define something that is discrete (in my model `b` defines the radial temperature dependence).

Comment: Thanks for adding the error messages. I can see now you're having theano issues, not PyMC3 ones. I'd recommend getting familiar with [the TensorVariable docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html), because they often require specialized methods for manipulation, which you're doing a lot of. Everything dependent on your RVs (`a,b,c`) is going to be of this type. For example, to round a TensorVariable one uses `theano.tensor.round()`.

Comment: Similarly, you can use `theano.tensor.lt` or `theano.tensor.gt` for `<` and `>`, and `theano.tensor.le` or `theano.tensor.ge` for `<=` or `>=`.